# AWS Lambda - Building serverless API using .NET Core

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api, aws-lambda, serverless

Recently I have been looking into AWS Lambdas and how to build Serverless API using .Net Core. From what I understand, you can do it in 2 different ways.

1) Write multiple separate Lambdas in C# and deploy them to AWS. Requests come in via API gateway and each lambda acts as an endpoint.

2) Build a Serverless Web API using .Net core. When you create the serverless Web API project a Lambda is automatically created which becomes the entry point to the Web API.

Are there any limitations of 1 vs 2, or use cases where one approach might be beneficial over other? Or is it just 2 different ways of achieving the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your options are correct. The two options for building a Lambda backed API are:

1- Build lambdas and deploy them independently to AWS in one or more project. Then Manually create API Gateway endpoints that point to your one or more lambdas.

2- Use a Serverless project to combine your lambdas in one project. Define your endpoints in that project and have Cloudformation create the API Gateway endpoints and hook them up to your lambdas on deployment.

As far as pros and cons,

***Option 1:***

**Pros:** has the flexibility of deploying lambdas independently, also you can configure your API Gateway endpoints however way you want without having to understand Cloudformation definition syntax which took some ramp up time in my experience.

**Cons:** If you have a lot of lambdas this becomes a management nightmare. Also your endpoint definition is not in the source code and changes to the endpoint configuration will not be tracked.

***Option 2:***

**Pros:** If you figure out Cloudformation or if you want to go with the default configuration deploying a lambda and hooking it to an API Gateway endpoint is super easy. AWS will create the endpoint for you and will create dev and prod stages, policies, IAM roles, etc. This being deployed by Cloudformation directly from Visual Studio causes the whole deployment and all related objects to fall under the same "Stack" in AWS Cloudformation which can be changed, repliocated, or deleted very easily. Also your Infrastructure is now code and changes to it are auditable in your git repo.

**Cons:** The biggest con in my opinion is the fact that the stack doesn't span the VS Solution but rather just the project, so all your lambdas have to live in the same project which means that if you have a lot they will end up all in one monolith lambda binary. The generated large project binary will costing you memory runtime on AWS and efficiency problems. The other con is that if you want to have specific or out of the ordinary API Gateway you will need to understand Cloudformation syntax to change your serverless.template file.

***Conclusion:*** My preferred solution was to divide my true application into smaller chunks of related lambdas based on the API object and place these lambdas in a few Serverless application projects. For example I have an order project which contains all lambdas related to the order API, and a Product project that contains the lambdas related to product API etc. Both of them would live in the same solution and would get deployed separately. I'm currently working on a way to deploy the entire solution at once.