# .NET Core | IdentityServer | AWS | Serverless | Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

Before everything:
I checked familar questions like:

- [access AWS API gateway using access token from identityserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52386062/access-aws-api-gateway-using-access-token-from-identityserver)
- [AWS Lambda - Building serverless API using .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50800104/aws-lambda-building-serverless-api-using-net-core)

And this one:

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/running-serverless-asp-net-core-web-apis-with-amazon-lambda/

But I still have question:

So. Lets say I have Simple microservices project.

I have:

- **Ocelot** - As Gateway
- **Identity server 4** - for All authorization and Authentication logic
- **Asp.Core MVC** - As my web project app.
- **Microsetrvice A**
- **Microservcie B**
- **RabbitMQ** - Event bus
- Some **databases** installed on premise....

Now I want to migrate this to serverless architecture..

From what I understand, I see here 2 options:

1. First Option

   - Is Launch....**EC2** (And this mean I need to pay for EC2 instance + Scale this EC2 instances) instance for deploy my Identity server.
   - Build **Authorization Lambda**.
   - Then Build AWS API Gateway. And All endpoint(which actually will AWS LAMBDA)  which required  protect by **Authorization Lambda**??
     This options mean...all time when I call Autorize protected endpoint - I will call 2 lambda funciton ( Authorize lambda + ) - If this correct?
2. Second options, (IF I understand right) - Is Deploy **Identity Server** as **AWS Lambda** as well?

Databases and **RabbitMQ** I switch to **Kinesis/SQS**, and **databases** to **RDS/DynamoDB**

Comment: Hello, any luck with this ? 
I need same setup for a project